# Bash command producing different results if typed in to terminal instead of copy and pasted

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, ubuntu-18.04, cut

New to linux, practising bash on a VM running Ubuntu through VirtualBox. 
Have a command to print the first character of each line in a text file which produces correct output:

```
cut -f 1- -d "^M" sample.txt | cut -c 1
```

However when i copy command from terminal and paste back into terminal using Ctrl+Shift+c and Crtl+Shift+v then execute, it gives me the following error:

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

*Edit: I type "^M" by holding Ctrl+v and hitting Carriage Return*

*Edit: Didn't realise Cut command operates on each line anyway, so first part of command in example given is useless, even so question remains valid.*

Comment: You sure there is no leading are trailing spaces or a newline?

Comment: Remove `cut -f 1- -d "^M"`. Just `cut -c1 sample.txt`. If `"^M"` is really a carriage return character the  `cut -f 1- -d "^M"` is a funny way to remove dos line endings.

Comment: How do you type `"^M"`? Do you type `^` followed by `M` or do you press `CTRL`+`M`? Please answer this in your question.

Comment: definately no leading trailing spaces or newline, i think Bodo is on the right track, when i type in ^M as opposed to Crtl+v+CarriageReturn i get the same error, if someone can articulate why this happens then i will accept answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only case I know in Linux where you get `^M` on your screen typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> is inside the text editor **vim** or **gvim**.

In that case, the text entered in your file is really a carriage return, but on the screen, you see the two characters `^M`. Since what you see is **not** what you get, copying and pasting it will lead to unpredictible results.

In Linux, the lines are not separated by carriage returns (hexadecimal code `0d` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>), but by line feeds (hexadecimal code `0a` or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>).

Comment: Im actually using the default terminal on ubuntu which is GNOME, but regardless i think your explanation is still applicable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing `^M` in a Windows file using a bash script, you might try to use `dos2unix` command, that's exactly what this command does.